# Is Possible to set a timer on when a function should run

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, mongoose, countdown

I have a button and when a user clicks on the button, it submits a form. But I only want them to be able to click on it just once. Also the button should go back to its original state i.e. become clickable again after 24 hours.

Please how do I go about this. This is the form and button,  I have thought about adding an event listener that just hides the button after it is clicked and after 24 hrs it shows again. Is that possible?

```
<form action="/earn" method="post" onsubmit='disableButton()'><button type="submit" id='btn' class="btn btn-info font-18">Earn</button></form>
```

I have a countdown that works fine but how do i set it that when the count down reaches 00:00:00, a particular block of code should run

```
setInterval(function time(){
  var d = new Date();
  var hours = 24 - d.getHours();
  var min = 60 - d.getMinutes();
  if((min + '').length == 1){
    min = '0' + min;
  }
  var sec = 60 - d.getSeconds();
  if((sec + '').length == 1){
        sec = '0' + sec;
  }
  jQuery('#the-final-countdown p').html(hours+':'+min+':'+sec)
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just add a timeout that has a duration of 24hs: `setTimeout(() => {yourCode()}, 1000*60*60*24);`

Answer (score 2):

> I have thought about adding an event listener that just hides the button after it is clicked and after 24 hrs it shows again. Is that possible?

Yes, that's pretty straightforward.

Here's code that would hide the button after it is clicked and then unhide it 24 hours later.  This is the simpler version that works when the web page is not refreshed.  To make it work even after a refresh, you will either have to control it server-side or use a cookie to remember when it should next be shown.

```
let button = document.getElementById("btn");
button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    button.style.visibility = "hidden";
    // show it again in 24 hours
    setTimeout(() => {
         button.style.display = "visible";
    }, 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24);
});
```

---

Also keep in mind that anyone who knows a bit about software can defeat this level of protection - this is purely to make the user interface show what you want it to.  If you need to prevent something from happening on the server for the next 24 hours, then you need to enforce that on the server itself.  You would probably use some persistent state associated with this user and then whenever you receive this form submission on the server, you would check that persistent state to see if the user is allowed to do this or not.